# Is the any primitive date type in IDL Language for Corba?

Tags: java, corba, idl

I have to implement an IDL specification for a distributed application with OMG CORBA. As i have to specify dates for some data structures i don't find any types defined for such purpose. Am i wrong ?

Please help !

Comment: Google search "corba idl types" turns up a wealth of information, including how to define your own type/classes, which you could use to wrap dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORBA COS Time Service does define some types related to time in the TimeBase module. These are used by CORBA Messaging, RTCORBA, and others. Check your CORBA implementation whether your vendor provides these.